# Select the inverse index in pd.Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

How to select the inverse index in pd.DataFrame by using `loc` or `iloc`?

I tried `df.loc[!my_index,my_feature]` but fail.

And `df.loc[[ind for ind in df.index.tolist() if ind not in my_index],my_feature]` looks too dull. Any better idea?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df.loc[df.index.difference(my_index),my_feature]
```

Alternatively [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
df.loc[np.setdiff1d(df.index, my_index),my_feature]
```

**Sample**:

```
my_index = [5,7]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a','a','a','b'], 'B': list(range(4)) }, index=[5,7,8,9])
print (df)
   A  B
5  a  0
7  a  1
8  a  2
9  b  3

print(df.loc[df.index.difference(my_index),'A'])
8    a
9    b
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

You may take advantage of `index.difference`.

```
idx2 = df.index.difference(my_index)
```

Or, `set.difference`

```
idx2 = set(df.index).difference(my_index) # note, order not guaranteed
```

```
df.loc[idx2, ...]
```

Comment: So, then for two dataframes it is simply `df.loc[df.index.difference(df_not.index)]`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming my_index are the row indices you want to ignore, you could drop these where they exist in the dataframe df:

`df = df.drop(my_index, errors='ignore')`